# Program crashed when variable declaration sequence is changed

Tags: c, memory-alignment

I had a very weird program crash issue.
I have 2 same piece of codes "Code A" and "Code B" as below.
In "Code B" I have just changed the sequence of variable declaration.

```
/******** Code A ******/
void MyFunction(char * ONOFF_Flag)
{
    short l_subchoice_s ;
    char  l_subchoice_ca[1] = {'\0'};
    char  l_ProcessName_ca[30];
    char  l_reply_c = '\0';
    char  l_Type_c = 'P';
    char  l_ProcessName1_ca[30];
    char  l_TCPIP_ca[30];
    char  l_TCPIP1_ca[30];

    /*
    Data Processing Logic
    */
}

/******** Code B ******/
void MyFunction(char * ONOFF_Flag)
{
    char  l_reply_c = '\0';
    short l_subchoice_s ;
    char  l_subchoice_ca[1] = {'\0'};
    char  l_ProcessName_ca[30];
    char  l_Type_c = 'P';
    char  l_ProcessName1_ca[30];
    char  l_TCPIP_ca[30];
    char  l_TCPIP1_ca[30];
    /*
    Data Processing Logic
    */
}
```

/* Data Processing Logic is as below */

```
printf("I"); /* CLSCR */
printf("\t\t  ONLINE PARAMETER READ MENU");
printf("\n\t\t  ==================================\n");
printf("\n\t\t  1. Profile %s for one Server",ONOFF_Flag);
printf("\n\t\t  2. Profile %s for ALL Servers",ONOFF_Flag);
printf("\n\t\t  3. Return to Previous Menu");
printf("\n\n\t\t  Enter choice  : ");
scanf("%s",&l_subchoice_ca);

l_subchoice_s = (short) atoi(l_subchoice_ca);

switch(l_subchoice_s)
{
    case 1:
      AllorOneFlag ='O';
      printf("\n\n\n\t\tEnter server name  $");
      scanf("%s",&l_ProcessName_ca);

      sprintf(l_ProcessName1_ca,"$%s",l_ProcessName_ca);
      memset(l_ProcessName_ca,'\0',strlen(l_ProcessName_ca));
      strcpy(l_ProcessName_ca,l_ProcessName1_ca);
      printf("\n\tDo you wish to do New Profile on/off the (Y/N)..?      :");
      scanf("%s",&l_reply_c);

      while  (l_reply_c != 'y' && l_reply_c != 'Y' &&l_reply_c != 'n' && l_reply_c != 'N' )
      {
        printf("\n\t Invalid Choice; Press (Y/N)              :");
        scanf("%s",&l_reply_c);
      }

        if(l_reply_c == 'y' || l_reply_c == 'Y' )
        {
          UpdateforOne(g_SystemNo_s, l_ProcessName_ca,l_Type_c);
        }
        break;

    case 2:
       AllorOneFlag ='A';
       printf("\n\tDo you wish to update parameter of ALL Servers (Y/N)..?      :");
       scanf("%s",&l_reply_c);
       while  (l_reply_c != 'y' && l_reply_c != 'Y' &&l_reply_c != 'n' && l_reply_c != 'N' )
       {
         printf("\n\t    Invalid Choice; Press (Y/N)              :");
         scanf("%s",&l_reply_c);
       }
       if(l_reply_c == 'y' || l_reply_c == 'Y' )
       {
         UpdateforAll(l_Type_c);
       }
        break;

    case 4:
       printf("I"); /* CLSCR */
       break;

    default:
        printf("\n\n\n\tThis is not a valid choice ");
}
```

This code is running for very long time on our servers and recently for some new requirements I need to modify it. When I tried adding function Myfunction() which is copy of another similar function, program crashed.

I did not get any compilation errors/warnings also.

When I compile and run program using "Code A", the 
program works fine but when the compilation is done using "Code B" i.e. change the variable declaration sequence, the program crashes.

I tried to debug the issue and found some memory corruption issue but not able to find the root cause of this.

Also this crash is not uniform, same program works fine on one system and gets crashed on another system. Same is the case on the system with 2 different logins. Program works with one login and crashes when compiled using another user.

Is this byte alignment issue? If yes then can anyone explain in detail.

I am running the program on HP Non-Stop G Series System where I faced the issue but 
it works fine on HP Non-Stop H Series System.
Compiler used on G series Systems is "nmc" and on H series System is "ccomp"

Comment: just a guess: what are you doing with `l_reply_c` in the function? I assume that the problem is not the declaration but in the `Data Processing Logic`. Could you publish the left out code?

Comment: we need code. and wie need a small example that demonstrates the problem (www.sscce.org)

Comment: There is little doubt your code is corrupting some data, but unless you show it we can hardly be more specific.

Comment: can you provide your Data Processing Logic?

Comment: Just a guess, there is a Buffur overflow causing undefined behaviour in not shown code.

Comment: @eckes, jayeshbhoi and Peter Miehle I have added rest of the part of code.

Comment: @kuroi neko forgot to add you in above comment. I have added the code

Answer (score 1):

if you have a code like "strncpy(l_TCPIP1_ca, "test", 40);" you get an undefined stack overflow. Now it depends on the underlying operation system and compiler, how the program behaves/crashes/corrupts data.

your EDITH:

```
char  l_reply_c = '\0';
scanf("%s",&l_reply_c);
```

if I type "ab" you get your overflow.

Comment: I have used strcpy(l_ProcessName_ca,l_ProcessName1_ca);

Comment: Actually, a single character is enough to write a '\0' past the single-char buffer, but alignment will probably make the overflow harmless until you go past 1, 3, 7 etc. chars, depending on alignment size.